# How to convert QDate to Python date object in PySide6

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt, pyside6, qdate

I have tried to get the date from QDateEdit so that I can save it to a database, but when I execute the code in PySide6 it gives me an error:

```
value = self.ui.dateEdit.date()
var_name = str(value.toPyDate())
```

Error:

```
PySide6.QtCore.QDate object has no attribute 'toPyDate'
```

If there is any other method apart from this to get a Python date from QDateEdit and save it to a database I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs for converting Qt date/time objects to Python ones differ between PyQt and PySide. For PySide2 and PySide6, you must do:

```
qdate = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
pydate = qdate.toPython()
```

(and this also works the same way for QDateTime objects).

For PyQt5/PyQt6, you must do:

```
qdate = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
pydate = qdate.toPyDate()

qdatetime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
pydatetime = qdate.toPyDateTime()
```

All of these PySide/PyQt APIs return a Python [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).